# JPanel will display buttons correctly, but won't display custom JComponent correctly

Tags: java, swing

I have a class `Cell` that extends `JComponent`.  The goal is for a grid of cells to be displayed, and each one be able to handle their own click events, etc.  It is basically a flat button.

When I add several cells to a `JPanel` only one of them is displayed.  If, using the same code, I replace my Cells with Buttons, everything works as expected.

What am I missing?

**Main Method**

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
    if(true){//Use buttons instead of cells
        jp.add(new JButton("Button 1"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Button 2"));
        jp.add(new JButton("Button 3"));
    }
    else{ //Use cells instead of buttons
        Cell a = new Cell(10,0,0);
        Cell b = new Cell(10,0,1);
        Cell c = new Cell(10,0,2);
        jp.add(a,0);
        jp.add(b,1);
        jp.add(c,2);
    }

    f.add(jp);
    f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

**Cell Class**

```
public class Cell extends JComponent{
    private static int numCells=0;
    private Dimension size;
    private int dt;
    private int dl;
    private Color color;
    public Cell(int size, int dt, int dl){
        numCells++;
        Random rand = new Random();
        this.size = new Dimension(size,size);
        this.dt = dt;
        this.dl = dl;
        this.color = new Color(//Random color, but only in one :r, g, or b
            (numCells%3==0)?rand.nextInt(255):0,
            (numCells%3==1)?rand.nextInt(255):0,
            (numCells%3==2)?rand.nextInt(255):0
    );
        this.setPreferredSize(this.size);
        this.setMaximumSize(this.size);
        this.setMinimumSize(this.size);
        this.setBackground(color);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setOpaque(true);
    }
    public void amClicked(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.getParent(), 
                this.toString());
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ""+dt+","+dl;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Graphics ng = g.create();
    try{
        super.paintComponent(ng);
        ng.setColor(color); 
        System.out.println(String.format("%d,%d,%d,%d(%d,%d,%d)",
                this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(),
                this.color.getRed(),this.color.getGreen(),this.color.getBlue()));
        ng.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
    finally{
        ng.dispose();
    }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 3 components, but only one is painted black.  Add a red line border to your Cells to see:

```
  public Cell(int size, int dt, int dl) {
     numCells++;
     //.... code deleted

     // !!this.color = new Color(Color.BLACK); // *** won't compile!
     color = Color.black;

     //.... code deleted

     this.setOpaque(true);
     setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 2));  // **** add this
  }
```

Edit: This line looks sketchy to me:

```
     g.fillRect(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

Why are you using getX and getY here?  These methods return a position information relative to the container not the cell, but then you are using it to draw in a location relative to the cell not the container, so the black rectangle will be drawn off of the visible cell, and this probably isn't what you want.  Perhaps you need to use 0 for both instead:

```
     g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

Comment: I originally had random colors, but wanted the color to be either only Red, only Green or only Blue. In an attempt to avoid confusion I removed that piece of code before posting.  I put it back as the "avoid confusion" part didn't work

Comment: I see why your code isn't working: it's your use of getX() and getY(). Please see my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious bug in this code is the fact that you apply changes to the Graphics object, via setColor(), but you don't roll them back.

This is clearly stated in the [Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29):

> If you override this in a subclass you should not make permanent changes to the passed in Graphics.

The general solution is to spawn a new Graphics object off of the you get as parameter via `Graphics.create()`, wrapping your code inside a `try-finally` block, and disposing the new Graphics object via `Graphics.dispose()` in the finally clause.